Hydration Issue with ProgressiveLoading in react 18

Suppose I have a component that produces ABC as output at the server side

that same component at the client side act as progressive loading to reduce the bundle size of the page which in turn returns null when the section is not visible on the client side

ProgressiveLoading Component

It is a HOC that sees if the component is in viewPort if it is then it downloads its bundle and attaches it.
Now in react 16 if there was a mismatch during hydration then we use to use suppressHydration props and set its dangerouslysetinnerhtml = ""
this used to make sure that if the page is server rendered then the whole page would render and then the component which was there in progressiveLoading would render but it would not get hydrated.


Now in react 18 it started to throw me an uncaught hydration exception is the any way to bypass that

Avoiding the hydration for sections which are wrapped in progressive loading


